# Make a subset dictionary from another dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, mapping

Here's my issue , hope someone can help I have what I call a global dictionary which in my scenario is a dictionary of all the possible `key:values` in my program

```
global_dict = dict(zip(legend_values_global, legend_colors_global))
```

and the values look something like this

```
{1: (191, 0, 0), 2: (191, 176, 0), 3: (29, 191, 0), 5: (0, 191, 147), 6: (0, 58, 191), etc
```

but now I need to make a dictionary of only the values that I need for a specific list. So if like `X` has only the values `1` `2` and `3` then I want a new dictionary that looks like

```
{1: (191, 0, 0), 2: (191, 176, 0), 3: (29, 191, 0)}
```

I do have a list called `uniqueBins` which has a list of tuples of the possible keys for each iteration

below is what I tried but I keep getting a `Key Error`

```
legend_colors_global = create_colors(len(legend_values_global))
        for bracket in bins:
            uniqueBins.append(tuple(sorted(set(bracket))))

        global_dict = dict(zip(legend_values_global, legend_colors_global))
        for i in range(waferNum):
            this_wafers_legend = {k: global_dict[k] for k in uniqueBins}
```

The format of `uniqueBins` is as follows:

`[(1, 2, 3) ,(5, 10, 11), (1,7,8)]`

The line `this_wafers_legend = {k: global_dict[k] for k in uniqueBins}`
is the one failing but I'm not sure why. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here :

```
{k: global_dict[k] for k in uniqueBins}
```

`uniqueBins` is `[(1, 2, 3), (5, 10, 11), (1, 7, 8)]` so `k for k in uniqueBins` is an entire `tuple` which ends up being `{(1, 2, 3): global_dict[(1, 2, 3)]}`. You can just create your dictionary using `k for k in uniqueBins[0]` if your target is keys `1, 2, 3`

```
uniqueBins = [(1, 2, 3), (5, 6, 2), (1, 3, 6)] # modified for provided data

this_wafers_legends = []
for i in uniqueBins:
    this_wafers_legends.append({k : global_dict[k] for k in i})

print(this_wafers_legends)
# [{1: (191, 0, 0), 2: (191, 176, 0), 3: (29, 191, 0)}, {5: (0, 191, 147), 6: (0, 58, 191), 2: (191, 176, 0)}, {1: (191, 0, 0), 3: (29, 191, 0), 6: (0, 58, 191)}]
```

Comment: no i would like to go through all the entire "uniqueBins" not just the first iterator

Comment: @JeffPernia   okay you can do that , will update, but still same idea, you cant pass the entire tuple at once

Comment: so just make another for loop in order to go through all my tuples in the list ?

Comment: @JeffPernia yes, not sure your plans on storing I did an example storing all the dicionaries in a list called `this_wafers_legend` but exactly you have to go one loop deeper